# Can I join two tables from different databases?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, arrays, join

I've got two different database tables which must (inner) join each other. One table comes from a MSSQL database and one is from a MySQL database. I'm almost sure it is not possible to join these tables on the database level, so I'll have to do this in PHP (the script language I am using).

Just to make some things clear, it's about getting order information. My MSSQL database has columns such as `order_id`, `order_description`, `delivery_date` , etc. My MySQL database has the same order ID with a state (such as "started", "paused", "ready", "delivered"). What I want is all the information joined in one table.

I was thinking about getting all the information from the MSSQL database and then SELECTing the state for each group from the MySQL database, but that's a huge performance issue: if I have 1000 rows I'll have to do 1000 SELECTs.

Something what would really be perfect is to do a simple SELECT on both databases, put the results in two different arrays and merge the arrays. I know there is a PHP function called `array_merge_recursive()`, but that just sticks the two arrays together instead of joining them on the primary key (`order_id`).

What is the best way to get both of the database tables in one overview?

Comment: The best option is to keep both tables on the same server.

Comment: Why would you have to do multiple selects? Can't you use OR.. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col='param' OR col1=param1` OR ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at creating a linked server to the MySQL Server from SQL Server. Then, you can code a join between the two tables as though they were on the same server. If you create a view, you can do a select on the view from your application. I would think it would be faster than doing the "join" in your application. It should certainly be easier to code.

To code the view, you would use a four-part naming convention to refer to the MySQL server:

Example:

```
select *
from mysqlsrv.mydb1..mytbl join
mssql.mydb2.dbo.myOtherTbl
```

Comment: I suppose the two databases are on the same server already, but I didn't know you could use 2 different databaseservers in one query. How should I launch the query since MySQL and MSSQL are having 2 different types of syntax?

Comment: You'll have to experiment, but, if you create a Linked Server on SQL Server, you use SQL Server syntax for the query. The MySQL ODBC driver will also need to be installed on the SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the keys from two arrays, which are equal, and only replace the values, you simply need [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

However, taking the information from both databases and writing it into an array is still the same as taking the info with SELECT and using the fetched rows as matches in another SELECT.

Comment: that's exactley what I ment in my last section; it's nothing more but just stick 2 arrays, to each other. That's fine, until the order of both arrays is not the same...